# how can I dynamically update datatable in shiny app? [r]

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to clear a datatable with an actionButton.
The chunk does work, but the table is still there. How can I update the content of the table when the actionButton is pressed?
Please find the toy sampel as following.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

    DT1 <- iris
  shinyApp(  
    ui <- 
      dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(title = ""),
        dashboardSidebar(),
        dashboardBody(
          DTOutput("DT"),
          actionButton("clear", "clear")
        )
      ),

    server <- 
      function(input, output, session) {
        output$DT <- renderDT(datatable(DT1))
        observeEvent(input$clear, {
          DT1 <- data.frame()
        })
      }
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need -

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
  dt_data <- reactiveValues(dt_data = iris)
  
  observeEvent(input$clear, {
    dt_data$dt_data <- data.frame() # use iris[0, ] if you want empty df
  })
  
  output$DT <- renderDT(datatable(dt_data$dt_data))
}
```

Comment: thank, you r right. The answere is so obvious and I was blind.